# What is the correct way to send and receive a custom file package via Messages on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm struggling to get a custom package to open in my app when a user receives the package via Messages (using iOS 13.6, Xcode 11.6).

My app defines a custom file type. It is a simple file package containing a json data file, and a directory of images

I’ve [exported the UTI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BIYy.png) (conforming to com.apple.package), [declared the document type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tSLP.png), and made a [QuickLook Preview extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaEoI.png)

I want users to be able to share these files amongst themselves, so I start the sharing flow by presenting a UIActivityViewController.

**Receiving the file via Messages**

- On the receiving end, the file is shown in the messages conversation
- Tapping on the received file opens a generic QuickLook Preview
- Tapping the share arrow doesn’t give my app as an option

The trouble seems to be revolving around how Messages is compressing the packages the user sends. This has led me to ask if I'm even doing this the correct way in the first place. Documentation isn't conclusive, so the question is:

*What is the correct way to receive a custom file package via Messages?*

Interesting side note:
This question is about being on the receiving end of the Messages conversation. If the sender of the file taps on the file in the Messages conversation, it previews correctly, and is able to be easily copied to the app

Comment: Share the code what you have tried

Comment: @Manimaran there is no code for this; only configuration in the Info.plist, which he already described.